# Retreive column names of a list and (list items) and export to excel using powershell script

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I need to retrieve  column names  of a list and export to Excel using PowerShell script. Can someone assist me to write a script for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this question is answered here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83641/export-all-the-columns-from-sharepoint-list-via-powershell/83658#83658

Answer (score 1):

try with the following code,

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null 
    $site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("YourSiteURL")
    $web = $site.RootWeb
    $list = $web.Lists["ListName"]
    $view = $list.Views["All Items"] 
    $items = $list.GetItems($view)
    $items | %{ select-object -input $_ -prop @{Name='Title';expression={$_.Title;}}, @{Name='ColumnName1';expression={$_["ColumnName1"];}}; } | Export-Csv -Path c:\test.csv -NoType 
    Remove-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

In the above script build your select object by giving the required columns names from the SPListItem properties before passing it to Export-CSV.